# How to host json-server in azure

Tags: javascript, json, angular, azure-web-app-service, json-server

I am new in the software field, please have patience with my question and mistakes of technical terms:

Premises:-
I have developed an front-end application using Angular4. The baseURL define in angular application is 'http://localhost:3000/'. My application uses restangular api to interact with json-server (I created a folder named json-server and it has db.json and public folder ). It is working perfectly fine when i start the json-server using command:
json-server json-server --watch db.json

My application is finalized and thus I created a production build. Thereafter I moved all my files from dist folder to public folder of json-server. When i start the json-server, my application works fine.

Actual problem:-
Now I wanted to host in azure. I simply copied all file/folder (db.json and public folder) from json-server folder as it is and put them in azure cloud. When azure hosting is done and I open the url in browser I got an error- "you don't have permission to view".

To rectify above error I deleted all files from azure and then I copied all files of dist folder and put them in azure cloud.  Using this I could able to see the application in the browser but no images. At image there is an error- Response with status: 0 for URL: null

When I start json-server locally, everything works fine but of course when same web page open from other machines I got the same error- Response with status: 0 for URL: null

Is there any way to run json-server in azure so that all machines/mobile when accessing the url, can see proper web page without any error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Step to step to run [*json-server*](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) on Azure Web App:

1. Open your browser and go to App Service Editor (`https://<your-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/`)
2. Run the command in the **Console** (Ctrl+Shift+C)

   ```
   npm install json-server --save-dev
   ```
3. Put all file/folder (`db.json` and public folder) into wwwroot folder
4. Create a `server.js` with the following content

   ```
   const jsonServer = require('json-server')
   const server = jsonServer.create()
   const router = jsonServer.router('db.json')
   const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults()

   server.use(middlewares)
   server.use(router)
   server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
     console.log('JSON Server is running')
   })
   ```
5. Click **Run** (Ctrl+F5), this will generate `web.config` file automatically and open your website in the browser.

   [image]

Comment: Can you please tell me where should I put server.js file.

Comment: Please put it under wwwroot folder.

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me a lot. Finally, I can now host it on Azure and everything starts working as expected.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following to quickly setup a mock service which can serve REST APIs off static JSON files.

[json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server)

Just install the NodeJS module ($npm install -g json-server). Populate a static json file in the format attached and then run the JSON server ($ json-server  --watch db.json --port 3000)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion but I actually want to host the json-server on azure.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the posted question